# How to choose between Linear Regression Methods

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, linear-regression

We have following methods to develop a linear regression model.
1. Ordinary Least square
2. Linear Algebra
3. Gradient Descent

How to choose between those models. Can anyone pls clarify the pros and cons of those?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Share relevant code snippet you have tried so far; in order to get expert's help.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that linear algebra is used to implement Ordinary Least Squares (OLS), such that in your question (1) and (2) are effectively the same thing. OLS can only be used for curve fitting equations that are linear in the coefficients and cannot directly be used for non-linear equations. Gradient descent is one of the ways to curve fit non-linear equations, but requires good starting parameters from which to begin the descent in error space.

I invite the more experienced statisticians on this list to comment on my small summary.